# How to Uninstall RVM?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-9.10, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove rvm (ruby version manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

How can I uninstall (or reinstall) RVM on Ubuntu 9.10? I messed up my current installation.

Answer (score 1076, accepted):

It’s easy; just do the following:

```
rvm implode
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

And don’t forget to remove the script calls in the following files:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.profile`

And maybe others depending on whatever shell you’re using.

Comment: #2 isn't needed. RVM isn't a gem, it's a shell script. An alternate to step #1 is to do `rm -rf ~/.rvm`.

Comment: Also make sure to close (and re-open if needed) the terminal afterwards.

Comment: @Tin, the rvm implode command does that

Comment: @theTinMan, [this answer (and some comments)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system/3558763#3558763) points out that `rvm` _can_ be installed as a gem.

Comment: im on osx and i edited .profile and .bash_profile but everytime i launch the terminal i get

    -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory

any ideas where else could this be called from?

Comment: hi sorry, I don't understand how to remove the script calls, what command do I type?

Comment: @philberndt I think it is somwehere in /etc/profile or /etc/profile.d/

Comment: @PedroC88, instead of reloading terminal, you can `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: i'm on ubuntu 14.04. I had to do both steps. also, I needed to edit .bashrc to remove rvm from that as well.

Comment: you need to do:

rvm implode --force

Comment: I'm on mac, and I had to do both and needed to remove rvm from shell. Same as @JasonShultz

Comment: Maybe removing references in .zshrc is a good idea too.

Comment: also `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Comment: In `Ubuntu 22.04`, I use this - `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/rvm`