# Made a mistake installing RVM with sudo. How to reverse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rvm

I am new to Rails and Linux and have installed RVM with sudo.

> sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s
>   https://raw.github/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)

Now I have to run most commands (like spork) with 'rvmsudo'. It is redundant, and the way I learned, when something is redundand it is often wrong. How to get rid of this nuance? Is the only way to reinstall RVM? If so, how to properly reinstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rvm implode` to uninstall rvm. Check that there are no environment variables left over in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash_profile` or whatever shell you're using. Once you do that, then re-install using the single user guide found [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/#explained).

You'll have to execute the `implode` command using sudo since you installed it as root.

Comment: When I go rvm remove it says this : 'Really? remove all? See "rvm list known" and limit the selection to something more sane please :)'?

Comment: ah, I see. Then in that case this is a duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/howto-uninstall-rvm

Answer (score 1):

1)remove in home directory:

```
rm -rf .rvm*
```

2)remove from your bash file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

3)  remove from /etc/rvmrc file

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvm*
```

4)Delete everything else

```
sudo groupdel rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a complete/concise step-by-step to 100% remove rvm when it was run as root. Here's what I came up with, and I've tested it three times successfully:

```
sudo su -
rvm implode
groupdel rvm
rm /etc/rvmrc
rm /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

You'll also want to double check that you don't have ~/.rvm or ~/.rvmrc or any rvm whatnot in your .bashrc (possibly .bash_profile on OSx), as you've likely been trying to install rvm several ways by this point!

Next, you'll need to reboot, as the global environment variables set in /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh will keep getting populated in new shells until you do. After rebooting, open a terminal and try this command to test:

```
echo $rvm_path
```

If it's empty, that means you've succeeded! If not, it'll most likely be set to `/usr/local/rvm`.