# Rvm ruby Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have installed rvm for multiuser,

when I am doing bundle install, it is giving me error,

```
linux:/var/rails_apps$ bundle install
ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use ruby` first.        

linux:/var/rails_apps$ rvm use ruby
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247': Permission denied
```

I already did,

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/rails_apps/
```

Please suggest..

Comment: It giving me `sudo: rvm: command not found` error

Comment: You probably installed RVM with sudo. Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932125/made-a-mistake-installing-rvm-with-sudo-how-to-reverse

Comment: Yes I have installed using rvm with sudo with this cmd `user$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable` refered http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: you can not use `sudo` for `rvm use` - sudo changes process and `rvm use` is supposed to change current process environment.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You have a multiuser installation of rvm - this is not recommended because of the troubles you can get with it (like yours).

Since you are already there this should fix it:

```
rvmsudo rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
rvm fix-permissions system
```

Also make sure you are in `rvm` group - if not add yourself:

```
rvm group add rvm $USER
```

and log in to a new shell (log out and log back in).

Comment: Thanks! For me `rvm fix-permissions` was enough to fix `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen`

Comment: Same for me `rvm fix-permissions system`did the trick, thanks

Comment: If you only care about permissions for a single user then you can just do `rvm fix-permissions`.  Here is the readme for that command: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/help/fix-permissions.md

Comment: I had to also run `rvm fix-permissions user` in my case, check the link given by @alli

Comment: For my ubuntu, what actually worked is: `rvm fix-permissions system; rvm fix-permissions user`

Comment: ahh thank you, that was what fixed it for me as well in fedora.

Answer (score 4):

In most of the cases `rvm fix-permissions` will resolve the problem for single user access but it fails in some cases while making other rvm commands thereafter. So do it with rvmsudo after the fix-permissions command consecutively as

```
rvm fix-permissions

rvmsudo rvm use ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who may have issues after running the commands shared on every thread out there, try opening ubuntu or the Linux environment you are working with as an administrator.

1 - Search for your app (in my case Ubuntu) using the search bar on the bottom-left of your computer's screen.

2 - if you don't see the option "open as administrator" on the right side, then right-click over the app's icon and you should see it then.

3 - Allow the app to make changes on your computer when prompted and then try the installation commands again.

4 - If that didn't work then try the commands shared in this or other posts, but always as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

this command bellow fixed the error on fedora 38 for me:

```
rvmsudo rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles

rvm fix-permissions system

rvm fix-permissions user
```