# ruby: usr/bin/environment ruby no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I am trying to install `gitlab`. I installed `postgresql` and I checked out the source. When I try to install by this command

```
sudo -u git -H./bin/install
```

I am getting

```
usr/bin/env ruby no such file or directory error
```

I have added ruby bin to my classpath. Below is the content of environement file under /env/

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin
ORACLE_HOME=/oraclebase/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID=orcl
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
```

I installed rmv as root. So the rmv installation directory is usr/local/rmv
If I check rmv list it shows ruby2.1.1 as default.

Comment: installing rvm as root is not recommended. Btw, `rvm` or `rmv`?

Comment: smy bad typing mistake. So what can I do ?

Comment: I mean how can I remove the existing installation. Then I have to reinstall it as normal user.

Comment: I guess so: http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: @UriAgassi Share some resources for uninstallation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/howto-uninstall-rvm

Answer (score 0):

it seems you haven't installed ruby correctly.

so first remove rvm

```
$ rvm implode
Are you SURE you wish for rvm to implode?
This will recursively remove /Users/gaurish/.rvm and other rvm traces?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
Removing rvm-shipped binaries (rvm-prompt, rvm, rvm-sudo rvm-shell and rvm-auto-ruby)
Removing rvm wrappers in /Users/gaurish/.rvm/bin
Hai! Removing /Users/gaurish/.rvm
```

next, install ruby:
try are couple of options to install ruby

per user using rvm:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

System-wide global

you can compile yourself from source:

```
$ wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar xf ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-2.1.1/
$ ./configure --disable-install-doc
$ make && make install
```

if everything went well, you should have a system-wide ruby available:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
```

For more see [installing ruby from source](http://www.gaurishsharma.com/2014/03/installing-ruby-from-source-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts.html)