# Failed to load SASS plugin

Tags: ruby, sass, rvm, bundler, compass

I'm using *Gulp*, *SASS* and *Compass* with *sass-css-importer* in order to build my project.

Today I've tried to initialize the project on one of my *Ubuntu 15.04* machines, but during the build it couldn't find the *sass-css-importer*. Here's the error message:

```
LoadError on line ["179"] of /home/sfomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: cannot load such file -- sass-css-importer
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I've installed *Ruby* via *RVM* and all dependencies via *Bundler*.

```
$ bundler list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.10.3)
  * sass (3.4.14)
  * sass-css-importer (1.0.0.beta.0)
```

And I'm invoking *Compass* through the *Gulp* task.

I'm not sure what could cause the problem with such amount of third-parties involved. I'm not into Ruby myself.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 15.04 \n \l

$ uname -a
Linux destiny 3.19.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 29 10:10:47 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

$ gem --version
2.4.8

$ bundler --version
Bundler version 1.10.3

$ sass --version
Sass 3.4.14 (Selective Steve)

$ compass --version
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2015 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass

$ gem query --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler (1.10.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
chunky_png (1.3.4)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
ffi (1.9.8)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.1)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.4.14)
sass-css-importer (1.0.0.beta.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was some weird issue with *RVM*.

Here's the steps to cure the situation in case you have the similar issue:

1. Uninstall RVM using instructions from this SO answer:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747195/1056679
2. Install Ruby following instructions from this article: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04 — use **rbenv** method.
3. Update you project and re-install all the dependencies from scratch.

Cheers!

Comment: In some cases, the issue's down to sass-css-importer actually not being installed [say you are running this in docker]. In such cases, in addition to what you've pointed out, running this resolves it: `gem install --pre sass-css-importer`