# Missing proper which command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm

I think I install Magnet in Mac and remove better touch tool, then my terminal suddenly gets this:

```
Last login: Tue Aug 15 16:23:47 on ttys000

ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!

WARNING:
      Errors sourcing '/Users/kenpeter/.rvm/scripts/base'.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.

ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!

WARNING:
      Errors sourcing '/Users/kenpeter/.rvm/scripts/base'.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
```

When I type which in terminal, it works.

My question is that, how do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

I did `yarn global install xxxx`. It causes rvm to complain.

```
yarn global remove xxxx
```

Fix the issue.

Ref:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20636?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2064

Answer (score 0):

I also received the

`Missing proper which command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM`

issue when starting my shell.

I use `nvm`, `avn`, and `rvm` and had `grunt-cli`, `karma-cli`, `typescript`, and `typings` installed globally via `yarn` when I started getting the error. After removing all of the global packages, the error disappeared.

I cannot reproduce the issue now, go figure. Just thought I'd share in case anyone has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, but **I finally got it working by reinstalling RVM**.

I didn't have much luck trying the solutions posted in the issues for this:

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2385

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4378

Nor with (re)installing RVM through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199).  Here are my notes:

```
# uninstalling RVM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747195/539149
rvm implode
# then delete all mentions of RVM in ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile ~/.zshrc

# installing RVM: http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/ https://rvm.io/rvm/install
gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
brew tap --repair
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
# add RVM to bash profile (usually in one of ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile ~/.zshrc)
nano ~/.bashrc
###
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
###
# reload shell settings
source ~/.bash_profile

# upgrading RVM: https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading
rvm get stable
```

I realize this isn't the greatest solution if you're in the middle of a project that's on fire (or maybe it is?).  But I think it's helpful to always have idempotent snippets that you can apply to remedy a situation, then optimize things later.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install node` fixed it for me, I was getting some node error when doing `\which`.