# Path's issue with bundler, to change or not to change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to setup a new rails 3 project with bundler, but i ran into issues with bundler.
I'm on rails 3.0.3 with ruby 1.8.7

When trying to do

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:52:in `initialize': Valid types are [:development, :runtime], not nil (ArgumentError)
```

Same goes for when I try to issue a regular rake task in my terminal, one like 
`$ rake -T` i.e., only then I get the error:

`uninitialized constant Bundler /Users/daniel/cc/contributie_data/Rakefile:4 (See full trace by running task with --trace)`

I've been reading some other questions regarding this problem, therefore i've learned it has something to do with paths...

`$ which rake`
/usr/bin/rake

`$ which ruby`
/usr/local/bin/ruby

Can anyone give me some suggestions about what could be happening here? 
And even more important, how I can get bundler to play nice with rake..

Thanks for any input on this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error (I'm using rvm). It turned out that in both my .profile and .bashrc was the following statement:

```
export PATH=~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

So this path was taken instead of the rvm path. I commented these lines out and now everything works fine

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete Gemfile.lock. It usually helps with

> Valid types are [:development, :runtime], not nil

error.

Answer (score 2):

Oh man, I just when through this today.

I did an update, and my rvm broke -- started throwing up on missing scripts and the like.  I just got finished completely reinstalling rvm and my rubies.

it's not great, and it takes a while but it's what I did to get back to a working state.

Started here.  [How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system) Ended up going through and installing fresh.

Answer (score 1):

I too face the same issue and resolved it with the help of this link [github:bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/592)

Modified a line in the file `lib/bundler/resolver.rb` which is reside inside `bundler gem`. Remove `*` mark from the line `d = Gem::Dependency.new(base.first.name, *reqs)`

like this:

```
reqs = [dep.requirement.as_list, base.first.version.to_s].flatten.compact
d = Gem::Dependency.new(base.first.name, *reqs)
```

to

```
reqs = [dep.requirement.as_list, base.first.version.to_s].flatten.compact
d = Gem::Dependency.new(base.first.name, reqs)
```

*modifying content of a gem directly is not a good practice. Posted this just to show another way to resolve this issue.