# Installing RVM on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm

I've got a strange error when I try to run this rvm install script (newly installed ubuntu 11.10):

> bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)

I got this:

> mkdir: cannot create directory: ”/usr/share/ruby-rvm/src”

The problem is, I want to install a *per-user* rvm to my $HOME, and dont understand what this script wants with `/usr/share/ruby-rvm`.

I need my rvm at `$HOME/.rvm` directory.

I've got no env variable with `$rvm_` prefix, I checked.

Comment: There was an unused package caused the problem. Solution:

> $ sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm

Comment: I need to wait 8 hrs for that

Comment: looks like zach got to it first

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may have installed the debian packaged rvm. You can clean it first with:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the same problem for me on Mint Linux.

Comment: Also may need to close and re-open your terminal window, if you have one open.

Answer (score 4):

In command prompt past the following lines:-

1)sudo apt-get update

2)sudo apt-get install curl

3)\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

4)source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

5)rvm requirements

6)rvm install ruby 1.9.3

7)rvm use ruby 1.9.3

8)rvm gemset create new-rails

9)rvm use @new-rails --default

Answer (score 2):

You should follow these instruction on [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) on Ryan Bigg's blog.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said by error message:

> To continue in insecure mode run 'echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc'.

Just run `echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc`. Then rerun;

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Comment: Worked perfect! I searched a lot to solve this problem, only this method worked. Thanks.