# Trying to Get Started With Rails on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am having some bumpy getting Rails running on my Ubuntu machine.  I was hoping that this script would be a no-brainer install:
https://github.com/rkjha/RailsOnUbuntu/blob/master/rails-installer.sh

But I ran into a slew of problems.  The first was that my Ubuntu issued rvm was messing with things, so I ran this solution:
[Installing RVM on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402827/installing-rvm-on-ubuntu)

However, I am still bumping my head against the following seemingly dumb problem:

./rails-installer.sh: line 38: /home/meawoppl/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

Comment: In the past I have had good success with Ryan Bigg tutorial on how to install rails on Ubuntu http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not follow [RVM site installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install):

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

This will install latest:

- rvm
- ruby
- rails

It will do short stop displaying commands to execute - but there is not much work to do, just copy/paste it to other terminal.

RVM2 will further simplify the above step so it all will be automated.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Rails Ready](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) script on Ubuntu several times and its pretty great. Highly useful and recommended.