# RVM installation issue on Ubuntu " No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm actually a newbie to Ubuntu (14.04) and RoR (development). So I want to get some help to resolve my error.
I was following a video tutorial and stuck in a command i.e.

`rvm get head and rvm reload`

that resulted me as

`No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones
rvm: command not found`

I interpreted it as RVM is not installed on Ubuntu. So I tried for it from many sources like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096382/3251831 and https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04#ruby but when I run the command

`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

It gives a message like

```
bash: /home/root2/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

I'm stuck here.

Comment: How did you install `rvm`?

Comment: I followed the gorails tutorial for it but at that time I picked the "Using rbenv" option in spite off "Using rvm" but later I tried many times to install rvm  but failed and failed always on third command i.e. "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you need to install rvm

follow the instructions on [rvm.io](http://rvm.io)

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Answer (score 3):

try and reload your entire shell or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```