# rails s not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My rails command suddenly stopped working

I am just typing command

```
rails s
```

and getting error

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

and command

```
  ruby -v   gives me

ruby 1.9.1p431 (2011-02-18 revision 30908) [i686-linux]
```

any help?

thanks in advance

Comment: Ruby 1.9.1 is not a supported version of Ruby. Upgrade to 1.9.2, or better yet, 1.9.3.

Comment: @sevenseacat I have installed both 1.9.3-p374 now i am getting error               ruby -v
bash: /home/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby: cannot execute binary file

Comment: is your user in the rvm group?

Comment: i have no idea about rvm group. and i get this output when i typed rvm use 1.9.3
Using /home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374

Comment: You should probably read the rvm documentation then.

Answer (score 2):

Please take care of your PATH variable, I had to remove also all ruby and rvm entries from `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile`. Maybe somewhere there your old ruby is specified.

Additionally: On my MACOSX_10.6.8 I just had problems updating ruby-1.9.3p125 to the newest version. So I did everything from scratch and removed (`rvm remove 1.9.3p125`) and also did `rvm implode` to remove the `~/.rvm` directory completely.

Check [How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

Later on:

- `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
- `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
- `rvm install 1.9.3`

After doing that, everything worked just fine!