# Unable to install gems or RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

I'm trying to install [Foundation with Sass and Compass](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compass.php) but am having a difficult time getting this, or any gem installed through terminal. I'm on a Macbook Pro running the latest version of OS X.

running **gem install zurb-foundation** or **gem install bundler** returns the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
can't convert Array into String
```

I get the same error for **$ sudo gem update --system --no-user-install**

What my **gem env** looks like:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-06 patchlevel 385) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: ["/Users/mc/.gems"]
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/mc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/mc/.gems/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
 - ruby
 - x86_64-darwin-12
- GEM PATHS:
 - ["/Users/mc/.gems"]
 - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "https://rubygems.org"]
 - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
 - "gempath" => ["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
 - "gemhome" => ["/Users/mc/.gems"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://rubygems.org/
 - https://rubygems.org
```

I have the latest version of xCode with the Command line tools add-on installed.

Something tells me it's a directory/permission issue, since if I log in as root on OS X, I have no issues. I've tried to use RVM to implode and reinstall ruby but shown in the screenshot below I always run into that same TypeError issue mentioned above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F2H1.jpg

Comment: run `gem list --local ` to show local gems

Comment: If you don't develope with ruby, don't use rvm. In order to compile ruby under Mac OS X, you must install a compatible compiler. I think these are not necessary for you to do compass jobs.

Comment: when I run gem list --local I see no local gems installed. Typically I'd use CodeKit to compile my Sass and JavaScript, but I'll look into some OS X compilers and avoid RVM, thank you.

Comment: Try macruby. http://macruby.org/

Answer (score 1):

First, by and large, I recommend [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) over [rvm](https://rvm.io/) for maintaining your rubies and associated gems. I find rbenv to be much easier to use as well as being less intrusive and a less of a pain in the behind with which to work.

Second, contrary to what ShiningRay commented, being able to maintain and use Ruby sandboxes is a big win. There are times you will want to try different rubies and/or gem versions out without

If you want to install rbenv, the easies way to do so is via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). If you install Homebrew, do so as a local install (do not use sudo to install it).

To install Hombrew, just execute the following at your prompt:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Before you install rbenv, you need to remove your existing - but apparently non-functioning - rvm installation. See [How to remove rvm (ruby version manager from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system) for how to do this effectively.

I believe you will have to run rvm implode via sudo to get this work for you.

Once you have installed Homebrew as a local user, then use it to install rbenv as outlined in the [rbenv Homebrew on Mac OS X section](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x).

**Important**
Do not run these commands as root! Do not use sudo. Just perform a local install of rbenv as you installed homebrew above.

In addition to rbenv and ruby-build, I would install the following rbenv extensions:

- [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset)
- [rbenv-bundler](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler)

**Note**
To be effective, and before installing it, rbenv-bundler requires you have [bundler](https://gembundler.com/) installed.

Now that you have done all of this, you are ready to start install the rubies and gems you need to install. I would create a gemset, associated with the ruby you want to use, and install the various gems you need to work with into it.

Comment: Thank you, @Jordan. I removed rvm and installed Homebrew + rbenv successfully but did receive the following warning after **brew install rbenv**:

`Warning: The cleaning step did not complete successfully Still, the installation was successful, so we will link it into your prefix`

I installed the rbenv-gemset extension, but not the rbenv-bundler as I run into the same problem as before while installing bundler. 

**gem install bundler** :

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    can't convert Array into String`

Seems I cannot execute gem install (anything).

Comment: I might have some time this weekend to dig into this further. If I can, I will update my response or add a comment here.