# Cannot source RVM files because of PowerPC architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, powerpc

I ran the railsinstaller from railsinstaller.org on my OS X 10.7.5, then ran into a few issues with RVM:

1) First, I got "RVM: command not found". So I created the .bash_profile and added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

2) Restarted the terminal, but still getting the same error message. I checked the .rvm folder to see if it's properly installed; it seems to be missing the "scripts" folder. So I ran

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

3) Then I get this:

```
Launch of "gtar" failed: the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported. Could not extract RVM sources.
```

Base on my research, this means that I need an Intel 64-bit machine. But I double checked and that is indeed what I have (Intel Core Duo 2). I've been spending hours trying to find more relevant documentations but to no avail, so I'm really stuck as I need the RVM for my projects.

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my research it appears that **Jewelry Box does not support newer versions of RVM**. I don't actually know if this is the issue that you're running into, but it seems likely.  I'd recommend uninstalling Jewelry Box and reinstalling RVM.

To reinstall RVM, you'll need to completely [remove RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system) and then use the same string you used before, but this time add --rails at the end, so you get rails as well.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

The other parts of rails installer should still be there like git and sm.

Jewelry Box will no longer be useful, but for that I highly recommend getting to know Bundler. The de facto standard for working with ruby gems. It'll be more useful when using rails and will be less likely to run into dependency issues.

Welcome Rails as well, stick with it and you'll be a pro in no time.  I highly recommend taking a look at [Rails Casts](http://railscasts.com). Very good short and digestable videos tutorials for rails.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Eric! So turns out the culprit was that I was using the C Shell instead of Bash! How silly. I realized this after hours of fiddling and updating the tar version (which was the reason why I couldn't pull the RVM files from the source in the first place). Since the C Shell was using the outdated tar, I switched to Bash, and surprisingly RVM works as expected (without having to re-install it, which I'm sure the reinstall would've worked per your answer). Anyhow thanks for the tips on the Bundler, will try it out!!

Comment: Just glad to hear you figured it out. I would've never guessed C Shell