# Could not extract RVM sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am trying to get rvm, gem, ruby, ir b, rails all installed, however, some issues occurred during installation.

`Could not extract RVM sources.`

now I am trying to **reinstall** rvm, gem, ruby, irb on Mac.

Here is the tutorial I was following:

- https://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/
- https://rvm.io

Now I am going through process mentioned in:

- [Cannot source RVM files because of PowerPC architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798260/cannot-source-rvm-files-because-of-powerpc-architecture)
- [How to remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

I am on `bash` shell, I have executed:

```
    rvm implode
    rm -rf /usr/local/rvm
    sudo rm /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
    sudo rm /etc/rvmrc
    sudo rm ~/.rvmrc
```

I have modified each of following to remove all reference to rvm:

```
    ~/.bashrc 
    ~/.bash_profile 
    ~/.profile 
    ~/.zshrc
    ~/.zlogin
```

then I called following command:

```
    gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
    
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
    
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

however the error shows again:

```
    Could not extract RVM sources.
```

It seems whatever I try it always end up this error, I am really frustrated.

Could someone please help me out.

---

#### Error

```
scripts/r

    tfm: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/rubygems: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/rvm: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/set: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/snapshot: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/tools: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/upgrade: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/wrapper: Can't unlink already-existing object
    scripts/zsh/: Can't restore time
    scripts/zsh/Completion/: Can't restore time
    scripts/zsh/Completion/_rvm: Could not remove symlink scripts/zsh/Completion/_rvm
    tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
    Could not extract RVM sources.
```

---

Previously I installed `gem` by rvm, I have uninstalled rvm, but the gem is still there, should I uninstall the gem first? if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is generally with some old rvm related stuffs in your system during installation error, hence they need a cleanup to fresh install the rvm.

**Try fixing the permissions with this ->**

```
rvmsudo rvm cleanup all
```

Comment: Would be great to add more explanation.