# Removing Gems errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have 2 versions of rubies using RVM and i am trying to remove all my gems which in this ruby `version 1.8.7-p302`

first i tried this but i got error

```
➜  ~  gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
Successfully uninstalled actionmailer-2.3.5
Successfully uninstalled actionmailer-2.3.18
Successfully uninstalled actionpack-2.3.5
Successfully uninstalled actionpack-2.3.18
Successfully uninstalled activerecord-2.3.5
Successfully uninstalled activerecord-2.3.18
Successfully uninstalled activeresource-2.3.5
Successfully uninstalled activeresource-2.3.18
Successfully uninstalled activesupport-2.3.5
Successfully uninstalled activesupport-2.3.18
Removing bundle
Successfully uninstalled bundler-1.3.5
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d bundler-unload`
```

then i tried this also an error

```
➜  ~  gem list --no-version | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
zsh: correct 'gem' to '.gem' [nyae]? n
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d bundler`
```

My Gemlist:

```
➜  ~  gem list                                                                                 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
fattr (2.2.1)
i18n (0.4.2)
mysql (2.9.1, 2.8.1)
rack (1.1.6, 1.0.1)
rails (2.3.18, 2.3.5)
rake (10.1.0, 0.8.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rush (0.6.8)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
session (3.1.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.8)
```

Update:

I have tried to remove ruby 1.8.7 then install it but the gems still there
when i type i got this

```
➜  ~  rvm gemset empty default
Are you SURE you wish to remove the installed gems for gemset 'ruby-1.8.7-p302' (/home/dexter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302)?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
➜  ~  gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
rake (10.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
➜  ~  gem list --no-version | xargs gem uninstall -aIx   
zsh: correct 'gem' to '.gem' [nyae]? n
INFO:  gem "bundler" is not installed
INFO:  gem "bundler-unload" is not installed
INFO:  gem "rake" is not installed
INFO:  gem "rubygems-bundler" is not installed
INFO:  gem "rvm" is not installed
```

Now i can not install rails again !

```
➜  ~  gem rails -v '2.3.5'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command rails
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**USING RVM**

1) Install rvm.

In the rest of the steps:

**DON'T EVER USE SUDO**

2) Install ruby (pick a version):

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

3) Make sure rvm's current ruby is the version you want to use for your app :

```
$ rvm list
```

and if necessary:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194  #Sometimes you have to specify the patch number as well, e.g p194
```

4) Create a gemset for your app:

```
$ rvm gemset create myapp_gemset
```

5) You can list the gemsets for the current ruby version:

```
$ rvm gemset list
```

and if necessary switch to the gemset you just created:

```
$ rvm gemset use myapp_gemset
```

6) Install the rails gem:

```
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

That command will install the gem into the current gemset.  You can check the version:

```
$ rails -v
```

There is a shortcut you can use to select the ruby version and a gemset you previously created for that ruby version:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194@myapp_gemset
```

You can also set a default ruby and gemset that will be selected when you open a new terminal window:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194@myapp_gemset --default
```

Or, you can set up your Gemfile in your app so that rvm switches to the specified ruby version and gemset when you change directories into your app's directory:

Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.3'   #(no patch number allowed here)
#ruby-gemset=myapp_gemset
```

rvm will read that comment in your Gemfile, and then switch to the ruby version on the previous line and the gemset specified in the comment.

.
.

https://rvm.io/gemsets/deleting

> **Deleting Gemsets**
>
> When you delete a gemset, rvm will prompt you to confirm the deletion.
>
> ```
> $ rvm gemset use albinochipmunk
> $ rvm gemset delete albinochipmunk
> ```
>
> To skip confirmation, pass the --force flag:
>
> ```
> $ rvm gemset use albinochipmunk
> $ rvm --force gemset delete albinochipmunk
> ```
>
> By default, rvm deletes gemsets from the currently selected Ruby
>   interpreter. To delete a gemset from a different interpreter, say
>   1.9.2, run your command this way:
>
> ```
> $ rvm 1.9.2 do gemset delete albinochipmunk
> ```

.

> If you don't use a gemset at all, you get the gems in the 'default' set

.

https://rvm.io/gemsets/emptying

> **Emptying Gemsets**
>
> If you empty a gemset, rvm will prompt you for
>   confirmation. This action removes all gems installed in the gemset.
>
> ```
> $ rvm gemset use albinochipmunk 
> $ rvm gemset empty albinochipmunk
> ```
>
> To skip confirmation, pass the --force flag:
>
> ```
> $ rvm gemset use albinochipmunk 
> $ rvm --force gemset empty albinochipmunk
> ```

Comment: i did not use a gem set ! , all i do is install a ruby version 1.8.7 then gem install rails -v 2.3.5

Comment: See additions to my post--you should empty the default gemset.

Comment: If you switch to a version of ruby `$ rvm use 1.8.7-p302`, then do `$ rvm gemset list`, you will see all the gemsets for that version.  The default and global gemsets are created automatically for you.  You probably shouldn't delete them.  If you switch to a gemset `$ rvm gemset use mygemsA` you can then see all the gems in the gemset by doing `$ gem list`.  That will allow you to confirm whether all your gems went into the default gemset.

Comment: see my update, i think i have to uninstall rvm to start from the beginning :S

Comment: Removing rvm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system

Comment: `Now i can not install rails again!`  Well, you have to use the right commands, and `$ gem rails -v '2.3.5'` ain't it.  Why all the panic?  Why do all beginners think the first course of action is delete/remove/erase?  Heck I'm surprised you didn't do: `$ cd /`  and then `$ rm -rf` to wipe your whole hard drive and then reinstall your whole operating system again.

Comment: And did you even create a gemset before trying to install the rails gem?

Comment: i just typed the first command of the solution in that link you gave then deleted the configuration from .zshrc and re-installed rvm again then i have installed rails 1.9.3 again but there is a gem list but does not include rails gem , i am installing it again , also i will re-install 1.8.7 i hope i wont get errors with it , also i did not create any gemset before installing rails

Comment: Okay, you NEED to create a gemset.  That is how you organize gems for your apps. Each app gets its own gemset.  So after installing rvm, then install a ruby `rvm install 1.9.3`.  Then make sure the current ruby is the version you want to use for your app `$ rvm list` and if necessary, `$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194`.   Then the first thing you should do is....CREATE A GEMSET: `rvm gemset create myapp_gemset`  (continued below)

Comment: Then you can list the gemsets for the current ruby `$ rvm gemset list` and if necessary switch to the gemset you just created `$ rvm gemset use myapp_gemset`.  Then you install the rails gem `$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0`.  That command will install the gem into the current gemset.

Answer (score 0):

RVM installs some gems in the `global` gemset you can uninstall those gems with:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall gem_name
```

if you do not want to use any gemsets (except the single per ruby gemset) use: this:

```
echo rvm_ignore_gemsets_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc
```

and from now on RVM will use only single gemset - no `global`