# Trouble running compass on OSX - LoadError on line ["51"]

Tags: ruby, sass, rvm, compass-sass

I read a lot of the issues here before, unfortunately non of the described solutions worked for me. I'm on OSX and using ruby-1.9.3-p448 via rvm. Everything freshly set up.

Then I did `sudo gem install compass` for getting compass and sass.
No error messages.

```
stnwbr$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

 stnwbr$ compass -v
 Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)

 stnwbr$ sass -v
 Sass 3.2.10 (Media Mark)
```

but as soon as I do something like `compass create` or `compass watch` I get:

```
stnwbr$ compass create
LoadError on line ["51"] of /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- breakpoint
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Including `--trace` the result is the following:

```
stnwbr$ compass create --trace
LoadError on line ["51"] of /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- breakpoint
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require'
  /Users/stnwbr/Dropbox/Projects/2013/11 OUA outdooradventures/OUA-sync/config.rb:1:in `get_binding'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `eval'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `block in _parse'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `block in new_from_file'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in `with_defaults'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in `configuration_for'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/installer_command.rb:9:in `configure!'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/stamp_pattern.rb:69:in `initialize'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
  /Users/stnwbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Unfortunately that's where my understanding stops. All ideas appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall sass and reinstall it with the following:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
```

For some reason

```
gem install compass
```

brings along some bleeding edge version of sass which is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I did sudo gem install compass

**NEVER**
ever
use SUDO
with rvm

Follow the instructions here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339927/removing-gems-errors/18340495#18340495)