# Sass Breakpoint causing Grunt error

Tags: sass, breakpoint-sass

Just did a fresh install on my MacBook with Mavericks. I'm using Yeoman and grunt to compile my project. After reinstalling and pull down the code from the repo, I see this error:

```
Warning: LoadError on line ["55"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: 
cannot load such file -- app/bower_components/compass-breakpoint/lib/breakpoint

Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.
```

I'm requiring Breakpoint in my gruntfile.js. If i remove the require, everything compiles as expected, without errors.

Let me know if I can provide any more details. Thanks

Comment: That answer fixed the issue: [link to stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373644/trouble-running-compass-on-osx-loaderror-on-line-51)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error appears to be caused by you not pointing to the correct file (that's what the `cannot load such file` error means), so double check that your import path is correct, but at the moment, you **must** use Breakpoint through Ruby Compass as it requires a bit of Ruby code in order to function properly. With Sass 3.3 available, this Ruby dependency goes away Breakpoint gets updated, but it will require a compiler compatible with Sass 3.3 (libsass, what powers `grunt-sass`, is not compatible with Sass 3.3, for instance).

I would encourage you to use `grunt-contrib-compass`, use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to manage Ruby version dependencies, and compile through Ruby Compass. These steps should resolve your issues.

Comment: excellent solved my issue thanks. I thought I need to have both the gem installed and the bower package for some reason.

Comment: @Snugug what if I want to remove compass complety and not use it. Is there any other way of making it work with grunt?

Comment: Breakpoint is available through Bower for any installation and available as an Eyeglass module for use with Node Sass and Eyeglass

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to go with NPM breakpoint. For installing:

npm install breakpoint-sass & add require 'breakpoint' in your config.rb file.