# Breakpoint installed with Bundler but still throwing 'not found or unreadable' error in Grunt

Tags: sass, bundler, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

I have installed [Breakpoint](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki) using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) as they suggest, included `require "breakpoint"` in my config.rb and included breakpoint in my main.scss file after compass.

### I am getting the following error when I run grunt to compile everything:

```
error app/styles/main.scss (Line 5: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
    /Users/craigmdennis/Sites/craigmdennis.com/app/styles
    /Users/craigmdennis/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets
    /Users/craigmdennis/Sites/craigmdennis.com/app/bower_components
    Compass::SpriteImporter)
```

So grunt can't find the specified file while leads me to believe it may not be installed correctly. It appears to be very similar to this issue: [Sass Breakpoint causing Grunt error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575737/sass-breakpoint-causing-grunt-error)

**I have tried installing another gem with Bundler and grunt fails to find that file too; ending up with the same error.**

This is the output when I run `bundle`:

```
Using sass (3.3.4)
Using chunky_png (1.3.0)
Using multi_json (1.9.2)
Using compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
Using compass-import-once (1.0.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
Using ffi (1.9.3)
Using rb-inotify (0.9.3)
Using rb-kqueue (0.2.2)
Using listen (1.1.6)
Using compass (1.0.0.alpha.19)
Using sassy-maps (0.3.2)
Using breakpoint (2.4.2)
Using bundler (1.5.3)
Your bundle is complete!
```

This indicates that the project is set to use the latest version of SASS as well as Compass version `1.0.0.alpha.19` which is above `13` [required by Breakpoint](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/Installation#requirements).

#### Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org';

gem "sass", "~>3.3.4";
gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0";
```

#### Here is my config.rb file:

```
require 'breakpoint';
```

#### Here is my main.scss file:

```
// Include Compass
@import "compass";

// Include Breakpoint
@import "breakpoint";
```

#### Here is the relevant part of my Gruntfile:

```
// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= config.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= config.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= config.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= config.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be happening? Or what I could do to further narrow down the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two issues going on. Firs issue is that your Compass Grunt options aren't pointing to your `config.rb` file, so Compass doesn't know to what to require. Grunt Contrib Compass has the ability to define what requires you want via the `require` option. The second issue is you haven't enabled the `bundleExec` option in Compass, which is needed if you want to run through Bundler. So, you should add the following to `compass.options` (assuming you don't want to read from your `config.rb` file:

`bundleExec: true,
require: ['breakpoint']`

Comment: I had literally just stumbled onto part of this answer. Works likes a charm now.