# How to move or uninstall gems from default System Ruby folder to RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have so many issues trying to update from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1 following the [guide](http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html) that I decided to uninstall Ruby, Rails and RVM (with all its gems) and start over.

RVM and Ruby Gone. [$ rvm remove](http://rvm.io/rubies/removing)

But still have a bunch of GEMS that I previously installed.

```
$gem list
```

As suggested on this answer, to remove all gems do:

```
$for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

But I bump again on the error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory
```

This is so frustrating! Using sudo does not make the fix either.

Even if I try to uninstall one by one, the system wont let me:

```
$rails uninstall

Could not find gem 'pg (~> 0.17.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Why do I need another Gem to uninstall a Gem?!

Comment: if you start using rvm these gems installed under `/library/` mean nothing - don't worry about cleaning up stuff you're not using at the moment.  IMO it's a waste of time to try and save a few mb of space.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do sudo gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

This SO question has some ideas: [getting rid of ruby gems that won't die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000731/getting-rid-of-ruby-gems-that-wont-die)

The answer to this SO question has step by step instructions to set it up properly: [Removing Gems errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339927/removing-gems-errors)

Comment: Don't do this. You can easily remove gems with the same name that are needed by Apple's code that uses Ruby.