# Why do I have duplicated gemsets after installing rvm and ruby ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, gemset

I just installed RVM on my laptop with :

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

It automatically installed ruby version 1.9.3.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
```

It automatically created the following gemsets :

```
rvm list gemsets

rvm gemsets

=> ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448@global [ x86_64 ]
```

However if I want to create a new gemset :

```
rvm use 1.9.3@rails3 --create
```

It responds me :

```
ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484'
```

If I type this command I will have duplicated gemsets :

```
douglas@bilbo:~$ rvm list gemsets

rvm gemsets

=> ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448@global [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p484@global [ x86_64 ]
```

So How should I proceed in order to simply have my gemset and one global gemset ?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstall rvm with the solution provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system) :

```
rvm implode
```

I re-install rvm

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

This time ruby was not automatically installed.
`rvm list gemsets` showed nothing.

So I Re-install ruby 1.9.3 :

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

And created my gemset :

```
rvm use 1.9.3@rails3 --create
gemset rails3 is not existing, creating.
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #gemset created /home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #generating rails3 wrappers.
Using /home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484 with gemset rails3
```

This solved my problem :

```
rvm list gemsets

rvm gemsets

   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p484@global [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3 [ x86_64 ]
```

However I still don't know why this happened ... ?