# Laravel/homestead - <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (Loa dError)

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am installing Laravel Homestead. (I have installed the latest Virtualbox and Vagrant). 
When I am using the following command

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I am getting the answer

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError) 
from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Please, help. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328019/cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb

Comment: I have tryied this commands rvm fix-permissions. The answer - bash: rvm: command not found.(((

Comment: Yes,it is saying rvm is not installed properly.First you have to fix that error.