# Removing RVM and File Paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system) to removing rvm and was wondering what I should remove within my  `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` files. I manually removed `/.rvm` and cannot find `.profile`. These are the paths that I have in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`:

**.bashrc**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

Do I need to remove anything? Maybe the first line?

**.bash_profile**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin:/Users/connorphillips/mongodb/bin
```

Should I remove all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `.bashrc` entire line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Edit the `.bash_profile` line to remove only the RVM paths, so your line becomes:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/connorphillips/mongodb/bin
```

Your particular system may not have a `.profile` file and that's fine.

Here's my script to remove RVM for the entire system, for all users.

https://github.com/SixArm/sixarm_unix_shell_scripts/blob/master/rvm-uninstall-danger

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Uninstall RVM (Ruby Version Manager). THIS IS DANGEROUS.
#
# This runs rvm implode, delete RVM files from the system,
# deletes /home/*/.rvmrc files and /home/*/.rvm directories,
# and uninstalls all RVM gems. We run this script as root.
#
# Adjust as you like for your needs. 
#
# Some of the script lines may report missing directories.
# For example, a Mac system typically has a /Users/ directory,
# whereas a Linux system typically has a /home/ directory.
# You can delete the lines that you don't need, if you like.
#
# If rvm implode gives errors like this loop:
#
#    line 72: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
#
# then the rvm setup is bonked and we can delete the rvm script
# by hand then run this script again; rvm implode won't work,
# but the rest of the script will do a decent job of deleting
# any lingering rvm files and reporting any remainders.
#
# Author: Joel Parker Henderson (joel@joelparkerhenderson.com)
# License: GPL
#
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

echo "rvm implode"
rvm implode

echo "remove rvm files from system-wide areas"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/rvm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/rvm
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc
sudo rm -rf /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

echo "remove rvm files from all likely user areas"
sudo rm -rf /home/*/.rvmrc
sudo rm -rf /home/*/.rvm
sudo rm -rf /Users/*/.rvmrc
sudo rm -rf /Users/*/.rvm

echo "remove rvm files from the current user's home"
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.rvmrc
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.rvm

echo "uninstall rvm gem"
gem uninstall -a -q rvm

echo "delete rvm group"
sudo /usr/sbin/groupdel rvm

echo "try to find any remaining .rvmrc files to delete by hand"
find -L / -name .rvmrc

echo "try to find rvm text in configuration files to edit by hand"
find -L / -type f | grep "\(bash_login\|bash_profile\|bashrc\|profile\|zshenv\|zshrc\|zlogin\|zlogout\|zprofile\)$" | xargs -I{} grep -Iil "rvm" {}
```

Comment: Hey @joelparkerhenderson thank you for your help. How should I run your script from the command line? Add all of this information to a file and then try to run it in terminal? Thanks again!

Comment: Also Would `.bash_login` also be a file of interest? There is reference to .rvm in that file.

`
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH" 
`

Comment: Yes, you can save that whole script as a file then run it. Or, you can simply copy/paste any line on your terminal because each line is independent. Yes, do bash_login as well; I will add that to the script on GitHub.