# "RVM install ruby" failed to install rubies, RVM installed in /usr/local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

when i executing  'RVM install 2.1.5', it gives me errors

```
Error running '__rvm_package_extract /usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-2.1.5.tar.bz2 /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_7085'
```

help me to fix this issues,thanks

here i added some more errors while installing ruby

```
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_7085: Permission denied
ruby-2.1.5 - #extracting ruby-2.1.5 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.1.5....
Error running '__rvm_package_extract /usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-2.1.5.tar.bz2 /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_7085',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1418271602_ruby-2.1.5/extract.log
++ [[ -d '' ]]
++ mkdir -p ''
mkdir: : No such file or directory
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ __rvm_tar xjf /usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-2.1.5.tar.bz2 -C ''
++ tar xjf /usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-2.1.5.tar.bz2 -C ''
tar: could not chdir to ''

++ return 1
++ return 1
++ __return=1
++ ((  __return == 0  ))
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ return 1
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

After up-gradation to MAC OS X Yosemite  it gives the error ,in mavericks it works fine

rvm info gives the following

```
ruby-2.1.3:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin D007.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.4 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "31 minutes 59 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.3p242"
    date:         "2014-09-19"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin13.0"
    patchlevel:   "2014-09-19 revision 47630"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/Users/prakash/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: What OS, Platform, etc? Post the output of `rum info`.

Comment: @prakashS I just saw your above comment. Sorry I have never worked on MacOS so I've removed my answer as it was in accordance to linux systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in permissions:

```
 mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_7085: Permission denied
```

You have RVM installed in `/usr/local`

I am running RVM on OS X Yosemite and have my RVM installed in my home directory:

```
 /Users/andy...
```

If you want to install globally like you have it, you will probably have to use the `sudo` command to complete the install. But I would highly recommend NOT doing that.

You should uninstall RVM and re-install it under your home directory. That is, open the terminal and ensure that you are in your home directory:

```
cd ~/
```

will put you in your home directory. Then install RVM and DO NOT use sudo, just install it with your regular permissions. That is the whole point of RVM, to keep the versions of Ruby separate.

Here is the Stack Overflow answer for removing all traces of the old RVM from your system before reinstalling:
[How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system?rq=1)
Be sure and pay attention to the part at the end about checking for modifications to your $PATH variable.