# How to uninstall RVM

Tags: bash, rvm

I installed RVM using:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

and now want to remove it from my system.  How can I delete the installation or undo this action?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from reading: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/

```
sudo rvm uninstall
```

For more info this might help:

```
rvm help uninstall
```

Comment: but rvm still install uncompletely! the above my command only part of the rvm's instalation. I stoped it and I want to purge previous installation before doing a new other install. However, when I run the command: `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`. It threw the error:`(7) Failed to connect to get.rvm.io port 443: Network is unreachable`. This is the reason why I want to clean up that installation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286533/128421 is the official way to remove RVM, documented on RVM's site.