# Uninstalling RVM -- what to remove on the files?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am following the instruction at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571648/3892201, and I am stuck at the

```
Check the following files and remove or comment out references to rvm

~/.bashrc 
~/.bash_profile 
~/.profile 
~/.zshrc
~/.zlogin
```

It says "remove or comment out "references" to rvm", and in my .bashrc file I see

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And I am really not sure whether I should remove the entire line or just "# Add RVM to PATH for scripting" part? I do understand English but I don't quite exactly know what "references" is meant to be?

And another question, in the following last part of instruction

```
 after making the change write using a bang!

:w!
```

What does the writer mean "write using a bang"? What do I have to write and what is a bang? I am so confused.

Comment: He means you can either delete the line or comment it, by putting a `#` in front of the `export` word.

Comment: The "bang" is this symbol: `!`. In vi (or vim), `w!` means to force-write the file to disk. `w` by itself means write the file, but if it was, for example, open in read-only mode, `w` alone will not write the changes to disk. There could be other reasons.