# mysql + ruby on rails + linux mint = doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint and I just started to learn Ruby on Rails. I'm following Lynda.com tutorials and I am getting stuck with setting up mysql. I tried everything that people asked before and I cannot find a solution. Let me explain.
I have all things installed correctly.

```
matth@MatijaComp ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
matth@MatijaComp ~ $ rails -v
Rails 4.2.3
matth@MatijaComp ~ $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

when I start a project with "-d mysql", start my mysql server, run "rake db:create", configure database.yml file to fill the password, then simply do "rails server". Hope I explained all my steps, maybe I forgot something, but I think I tried everything. Setting the password is not the problem. ( without mysql rails server works fine)

```
[2015-07-25 02:58:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-25 02:58:46] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-07-25 02:58:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11689 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-25 02:58:48 +0200

Gem::LoadError (Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).):
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

It always shows this error, whatever I try to do. Even if I remove gems for mysql, comment the database in database.yml, it still doesn't want to work.
Thank you!

Comment: try `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try running `bundle exec rails s` and see if it gives a different result. If it complains that you haven't run bundler, first run `bundle install`. A `Gem::LoadError` generally means there's an issue with your Gemfile, and sometimes -- e.g., if you installed Ruby via your system package manager or an installer -- the `rails` binary will be linked to your system gems and not your project's gems. Prefixing commands with `bundle exec` ensures they run in the context of your current Gemfile.

Comment: now I explored new problem with rails.. when i type `rails -v` outside project it says that correct version is installed, but when I enter in the project directory it says that
`Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run "gem pristine --all" for better startup performance.`
and when i try to update rubygems it says its updated.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed my problem by removing all things connected with RVM ( [rvm-removing-guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system) )because it causes some problems with gems. It might happened because I used few installing guides in the same time. Then I used one guide and installed ruby and rails with `rbenv` ( [ror-installing-guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10) ).