# cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb when trying to uninstall rvm

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I'm kind of new to Ubuntu.
I got this error when trying to install bundle:

```
$ sudo gem install bundle
 ⏎  <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require':
 ⏎  cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)    from
 ⏎  <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

In some similar problems, it was suggested to remove rvm and ruby completelty, so I tried following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system).

`rvm preload` worked, but when trying to `gem uninstall rvm` I got the same message...

```
$ gem uninstall rvm
 ⏎  <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- > rubygems.rb (LoadError)
 ⏎  from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

When i did `ruby -v`, I got:

```
$ ruby -v
 ⏎  The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 ⏎   * ruby
 ⏎   * ruby1.8
 ⏎  Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I tried to `sudo apt-get install ruby` as suggested, it returned:

> ruby is already the newest version.
>
> [...]
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I want to clean all of the ruby-related packages from my computer and start it all anew. Can you please help me doing that?

Some more details that may help:

Before doing `rvm` implode, I cleaned every rvm or gem related lines from my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/ruby
```

and

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ruby
```

return an empty dir.

`/usr/lib` has no other interesting directories, but `/usr/bin` has:

```
$ ls /usr/bin
 ⏎   [...] rake rake1.9.1 rake2.2 rdoc 
 ⏎   rdoc1.9.1 rdoc2.2 ri ri1.9.1 ri2.2 ruby1.9.1 ruby2.2
```

`/usr/local/lib` also had no interesting directories, but:

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin
 ⏎   [...]   bundle  bundler  rake
```

Comment: `gem uninstall rvm` rvm is not a gem.

Comment: It's the most rated anser at the link I added. Is it not what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby developers usually prefer to use rvm, that implies that ruby and gems will be managed as part of rvm and you must avoid install all ruby related software with the OS tools (apt, yum, pacman, etc).

Install mc (it's helpful to learn linux) and curl:

```
sudo apt install mc curl && mc
```

In the "panel" options active the option "Show hidden files", delete your .rvm dir with F8. Leave mc and run as normal user:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: Thank you! I have two questions: 
a. Why did I need mc? Wouldn't a simple ls -a have worked? 
b. Removing .rvm seem to have worked, but now I get the same error trying to 'gem install bundle' or run 'bundle -v' ('which bundle' returns '/usr/local/bin/bundle'). Does it mean I didn't really removed everything and started from the top like I hoped?

Comment: 1) Seemed to me that you are kind of new on Linux, so I suggested using MC because it can show you extra information in a more visual way. But no, it's not necessary.

2) Try to avoid using "sudo" in all the rvm, ruby, gems stuff. First install rvm, rvm is NOT a gem so,  "gem uninstall rvm" doesn't make sense. Then install bundle with gem.

Answer (score 0):

When running `gem install`, do not use `sudo`.

If you want to use `rvm`, do not install ruby through the package manager using `sudo apt-get install ruby`.

Comment: Thank you, first of all. I didn't use sudo on gem install, all commands in my question are exactly as I used them. I'm trying to delete everything and start it all over again, but the missing .rb file won't let me do that in the ways I found on other questions here.

Comment: 2nd line of your post reads `sudo gem install bundle`. Looks like you did?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad... But why is that a problem? Why should 'sudo' not be used when installing things?