# How do I upgrade RVM when the official way doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Namaste!

Wanting to check out the shiny new Rails 5.0, I bumped into an error saying I need to upgrade my Ruby version to a minimum 2.0.0 (my current version being 2.1.3). I use RVM to manage Rubies on my OSX, so I tried the good ol'

> rvm install ruby --latest

...only to be told

> Already installed ruby-2.1.3.

I ran

> rvm known list

...and indeed, the latest version of Ruby listed was the one I already have, i.e, 2.1.3. Next, I checked my RVM version and found it to be 1.25.31, while the RVM blog states 1.27.x was recently released. So I decided maybe this is the reason the known list doesn't show newer Ruby versions and used the documented [steps of upgrading RVM from their site](https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading). After reloading, I still see the same version of RVM and the same list of available Ruby versions. I tried restarting Terminal too. What do I do now?

Comment: Do you have to use RVM? RVM is great, but I switched to **rbenv** a long time ago—I've found it better for my style of dev: just include a `.ruby-version` file in your app's root dir. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: Well, unfortunately I'm tied to using RVM right now. I'm aware of rbenv and it's awesomeness too, but a RVM-specific solution for now would be better and much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install RVM from scratch**

1) First remove the current version, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558763/1076207

```
# use sudo at your own discretion
rvm implode --force
gem uninstall rvm
rm -rf ~/.rvm

# open file
vim ~/.bash_profile
# remove lines:
# [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
# close file
```

2) Follow the directions on the RVM install page: https://rvm.io/rvm/install