# rake commands not working - /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm, rbenv

`RVM` got installed in my system for mistake.

I am using `rbenv` and this caused problems in my `Ruby on Rails` apps.

[I uninstalled successfully `rvm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system), in one of my apps I need to run `rake db:create:all` to build the psql database and I receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: Not a directory
```

the file `/usr/bin/env` is type program not directory.

The problem is connected to `rake`. I can build the db by running `rails db:create:all`. Also other `rake` commands like `rake db:migrate` trigger the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gem install rake` solved the problem