# After opening PhpStorm is running with errors

Tags: phpstorm

A few days ago my **PhpStorm** is starting to working a bit strange. It starts working after I open Terminal. IDE is open with errors

> - Cannot find file '~/-p'
> - Cannot find file '~/-o'
> - Cannot find file '~/ucomm='

What files is it? How can a fix/investigate this problem?

Comment: **1)** Check `idea.log` file (`Help | Show Log in XXX` if you can launch IDE .. or [check here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for actual location) **2)** Possibly you just need to reinstall it (e.g. installation is corrupted somehow). At very least try that.

Comment: I completely removed PHPStorm and now my terminal is showing info when I'm after loading: "The file /Applications/PhpStorm.app does not exist". So, there is some script that wants to open PHPStorm after terminal loads. How can I find it?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so will not be able to help much .. but I think *it might be* references to a launcher script that you create from `Tools` menu (in PhpStorm) so you can open current folder as a project from Terminal. Check you OS for `pstorm` (?) executable file (I believe it will be a shell or python script). Other than that -- could be your shell config (`.bash_profile`, `.profile` or alike file) -- the one that sets up your Terminal environment/config.

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for your answer. I've found some strange things in the .bash_profile, RMV is running some scripts, which are want to use PHPStorm. I've followed instructions from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571648/2392957 and everything is working good now. Thanks again!