# Passenger and rbenv issue - incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, rbenv

Lately I moved from RVM to Rbenv. I run a bunch of different rails applications (each has a different ruby version) with `passenger` and `nginx`.
However, I get an error for two applications when trying to load them:

```
/user_folder/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': incompatible library version - /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.2_1/libexec/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.3.3-x86_64-macosx/passenger_native_support.bundle (fatal)
    from /user_folder/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.2_1/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:427:in `load_native_extension'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.2_1/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:103:in `load_from_buildout_dir'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.2_1/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:39:in `try_load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.2_1/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:50:in `start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.2_1/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:443:in `<top (required)>'
```

Other apps are working fine, and those work when I use `webrick` (standalone) instead. But for some reason, I have issues when doing so with `passenger`.

I'm not sure whether it's a coincidence or not, but both apps I have issues with are running ruby `v2.3.3`.

Any idea on what's happening?

Comment: did you re-installed the ruby gems after switching to `rbenv`? Above issue may have raised due to mismatch of ruby `gemset` path.

Comment: @UdAY I actually run a `gem pristine --all`. However, after all of this, I remove rbenv and got back to rvm and the issue persists. So that doesn't seem to be related to the  ruby version manager at all. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you should **remove rvm**

This [post explains how to remove rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system), additionally there is a *dangerous*, but [yet **effective** rvm implode script](https://github.com/sixarm/rvm-implode-systemwide-danger).

The output you are receiving is not from `rbenv` but `rvm`.

```
build-native-support. [passenger_native_support.bundle] trying to compile for the current user and Ruby interpreter... (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable) Compilation successful. The logs are here: /var/folders/_n/pb7r0l3x4kjgcvbdxj30nyn00000gn/T/passenger_native_support-142p5a1.log [passenger_native_support.bundle] successfully loaded.
```

This could be caused from different issues, I would go through the whole procedure of `rvm` removal and `rbenv` installation.

`rbenv` and `rvm` use an environment variable to intercept your commands.

You don't have a `passenger` or `passenger-config` binary in your system `$PATH` (which is a list of folders in your `home` directory), the `passenger` binaries are installed from `rbenv` and stored inside the `.rbenv/<ruby-version>` folder.

Each version of `ruby` has separate dependencies.

`rbenv` intercepts your commands (`passenger-config`) and run the correct `binary` (`.rbenv/<ruby-version>/gems/passenger/passenger-config`) based on the `ruby-version` you set up either `globally` or `locally`.

`rvm` probably works with a similar methodology and it is incompatible with `rbenv`.

For this reason you need to check your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or any other terminal config profile settings for the `rvm` env variables and remove them.

Once you correctly installed `rbenv`, run a `command line interface` command `passenger-config`

```
passenger-config build-native-support
```

and also consider checking out [`Passenger + Nginx` installation instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/osx/).

Comment: This didn't work for me. And I need passenger to run with Nginx, I'm not interested in the standalone version. Thanks though!

Comment: @ArielScherman [passenger with nginx installation instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/installation/ruby/), once you installed the gem, `passenger-config` should be available globally in your terminal and you can run `build-native-support`. Please output the result of running those commands

Comment: I've tried that and I got this message when running the `build-native-support`. `[passenger_native_support.bundle] trying to compile for the current user and Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Compilation successful. The logs are here:
     /var/folders/_n/pb7r0l3x4kjgcvbdxj30nyn00000gn/T/passenger_native_support-142p5a1.log
 [passenger_native_support.bundle] successfully loaded.`
However, it still doesn't work (I've restarted everything))

Comment: @ArielScherman your issues is caused from not correctly removing `rvm` and updating your `bash_profile` environment variables. I update my answer

Answer (score -2):

Something's corrupted in your ruby 2.3.3 environment.

Try '*gem uninstall passenger*', follow prompts to uninstall ALL versions(if any). Then install passenger gem. Then hopefully you'll be able to get rid of this issue.

Just to ensure, make sure that you have set the passenger_ruby to 2.3.3 path at corresponding virtual host entry.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. The `passenger_ruby` is set correctly to 2.3.3. I have another project with a different ruby version that is working fine, the problem seems to be only for projects with ruby 2.3.3. Any ideas?