# uninitialized constant Sprockets::Engines (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, rbenv, sprockets

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, Ruby 2.6.3, and Rails 6. I'm working on a new rails project, and when i start the server, i have the following error :

```
> rails s

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
    72: from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    71: from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    70: from /home/franck/code/BTC1M/app-test/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    69: from /home/franck/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    68: from /home/franck/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    67: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    66: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
[...]
5: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
4: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/less-rails-2.6.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:17:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
3: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
2: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
1: from /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Engines (NameError)
```

I tried to uninstall and re-install rails and ruby (through those steps) :

```
rvm implode
rm -rf ~/.rvm
rm -rf ~/.rbenv
sudo apt install -y build-essential tklib zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libreadline-dev
sudo apt clean
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
rbenv install 2.6.3
rbenv global 2.6.3
gem install rails
```

I also tried `spring stop`, and updating sprockets and sprockets-rails : `gem update` (my sprockets-rails version is 3.2.1), and updating the sprockets-rails version in Gemfile.lock : `sprockets-rails (3.2.1)`. My sprockets version is 4.0.0.

I also added `gem 'sprockets', git: 'git://github.com/rails/sprockets'` in my gemfile + `bundle install` (as it was told on this thread : https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/48 ) but it doesn't fix my issue.

I still have the same error. I don't understand what is going on. Any idea ?

By the way, why do i have a /home/franck/.rvm folder (that i deleted before) as i'm not using RVM but RBENV ?

The github repo is here : https://github.com/BTC1M/app-test

Comment: try running `spring stop` or check if there's any `spring` process running on the machine and kill it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing one by one those old dependencies that might not be compatible with `rails > 5`, and bundle again:

- Start with `gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'` which last commit is 5 years ago, and which is referenced in your error stack.

Also look at those other dependencies:

- `gem 'jquery-easing-rails'` last commit is 5 yo
- `gem "font-awesome-rails"` last commit 3 yo

Also note that `bootstrap-sass` and `font-awesome-rails` doesn't support latest versions of those libraries, and might need some hacking to work on Rails 6, you'd better use those librairies with `webpack` which is the new standard (Sprocket does not handle JS by default anymore, everything happens in `app/javascript` which is compiled by `webpack`).

And, you might not need `therubyracer` anymore (last commit 3 yo and a lot of recent issues).