# problem to start rails server "bundle exec rails serve" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I tried to run `bundle exec rails server` to start the app, I got this message below. Anyone has an idea about this issue?

```
bundle exec rails server
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

Exiting Traceback (most recent call last):
49: from bin/rails:4:in <main>' 48: from bin/rails:4:in require'
47: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in <top (required)>' 46: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in invoke'
45: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in perform' 44: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor.rb:369:in dispatch'
43: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in invoke_command' 42: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in run'
41: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in perform' 40: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in tap'
39: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in block in perform' 38: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in start'
37: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in log_to_stdout' 36: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in wrapped_app'
35: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in app' 34: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in app'
33: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in build_app_and_options_from_config' 32: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file'
31: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in new_from_string' 30: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in eval'
29: from config.ru:in <main>' 28: from config.ru:in new'
27: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in initialize' 26: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in instance_eval'
25: from config.ru:3:in block in <main>' 24: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in require'
23: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in require' 22: from /home/ubuntu/PINGOWebApp-rails51/config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
21: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in initialize!' 20: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in run_initializers'
19: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in tsort_each' 18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in tsort_each'
17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in each_strongly_connected_component' 16: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in call'
15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in each' 14: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in block in each_strongly_connected_component'
13: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in each_strongly_connected_component_from' 12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in block in tsort_each' 10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in block in run_initializers'
9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in run' 8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in instance_exec'
7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:81:in block in <module:Bootstrap>' 6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in run_load_hooks'
5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in each' 4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in block in run_load_hooks'
3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in execute_hook' 2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in with_execution_control'
1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in block in execute_hook' /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:15:in block in class:Railtie': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Engines (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new, sorry if it don't work.

from this post
[uninitialized constant Sprockets::Engines (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480879/uninitialized-constant-sprocketsengines-nameerror)

try `spring stop` then relaunch your server.
or
`gem update`

if it don' work, desinstall some gems mentionned in your problem until you localize the faulty gem.

hope, it can help

Answer (score 0):

gem sprocket is causing the error.

You can resolve this. Go to the terminal and uninstall sprockets If it is installed
you can check list of installed gems using `gem list`

and to uninstall it Run `gem uninstall sprockets`

then go to Gemfile and add following line

> `gem 'sprockets', git: 'git://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git'`

now simply run `bundle install` on terminal and you can start your sever now using `rails server` on terminal

Comment: i did that but after running bundle install i got this message error: Could not find gem 'sprockets' in git://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git (at master@8ef4c11).
The source does not contain any versions of 'sprockets'