# Rails bootsnap `cannot load such file` error after MacOS Big Sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, macos-big-sur, bootsnap

After updating to Big Sur, rails no longer runs my application. `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@my_app/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in require': cannot load such file -- /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@my_app/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.10.0.364/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_storage.rb (LoadError)`

The error is not specific to a gem as it will throw the same error for different gems. I have tried reinstalling rvm, bundler, and all my libraries (pretty much everything i can think of) and nothing has resolved this issue. Any ideas to try solving this are appreciated.

Clearing the bootsnap cache in the app tmp folder does not solve the problem. It only changes the error each time to a different `cannot load such file -- some different gem` or it throws an error that looks like `/Users/tomblais/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@crm-web/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:13:in compile_file': Interrupted system call @ rb_sysopen - /Users/tomblais/Documents/starburstLabs/crm-web/app/helpers/email_connect/email_templates_helper.rb (Errno::EINTR)`

UPDATE: I have since wiped my drive and done a clean install of MacOS Big Sur, set everything up yesterday and it was working great. Go to run my program today and get the same sort of error as I have listed above, no idea whats going on here.

Comment: Explain in detail how you removed and reinstalled RVM, Ruby, and your gems.

Comment: After using `rvm uninstall ruby-version` for each ruby version i had installed i followed steps from this forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system to completely remove rvm. Afterwards i went through my file finder and made sure anything rvm related was removed

Comment: Open IRB and `require` some gem you have installed and report back on the outcome.

Comment: `6: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/irb:23:in '<main>'
5: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/irb:23:in 'load'
4: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in '<top (required)>'
3: from (irb):1
2: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
1: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
LoadError (cannot load such file -- active-admin)`

Comment: sorry its hard to read, but some of the gems load ok and others return something similar to the above error

Comment: It's generally better to put that kind of info in the question so it's easier to read, but I can read it well enough. Are you sure ActiveAdmin is installed? Did you do `gem install active-admin` first?

Comment: yes even if i install the gem first i still get the same error, im thinking some sort of file path issue must have occurred after updating but i have no idea how to go about fixing it

Comment: I think that the problem is that you have installed the gems for a different version of Ruby. Do you have a `.ruby-version` file or a version specified in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes, using version 2.6.6 specified in a `.ruby-version` file. Using RVM to set my version. I have tried installing gems multiple times to a project specific gemset as well as to the ruby version itself.

Comment: @tgbrock did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue, also on BigSur and with rbenv. I updated brew, reinstalled the rbenv version, and still had issue.

Comment: @CAB Never found a solution. Ended up wiping my mac completely clean and reinstalled Big Sur. Everything was fine after this. One thing to look into however is the 'new_relic" gem. I believe this gem may have been the root of many of the issues i had.

Comment: For me it was having the newrelic dependency. I removed that locally and it all went away :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the Real Time protection of the Antivirus Software (Intego Virus Barrier).
Turning it off solved.