# Ruby Environment messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey so I hoping to get some advice about un-messing up my ruby environment. I ran into some issues when updating my ruby version. I realized that I had both rvm and rbenv, and I read that having both could be problematic. I deleted rvm with:

```
rvm implode
```

I used rbenv to install and select the ruby version I want. However now I am receiving the error:

```
Library not loaded: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
```

How can I get my environment to look wherever rbenv downloaded ruby instead of rvm?

Comment: Clearly there's still some stuff relating to RVM on your machine. In particular, modifications to your `PATH`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558763/1954610, and possibly restart your computer to get rid of it all.

Comment: You need to specify how the error happens. If it's when you try to bundle it is most likely just that you forgot to change the SDK in your IDE. You can do this by going to settings and search for SDK, then swap to Rbenv. If not, and the error happens in your cmd it depends on which OCR you're using.