# RVM / Rbenv issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am struggling with an issue. I am quite new and so hopefully makes some sense my q below!

I removed rvm and installed rbenv
when i do rails s to start server on a project... (i.e. rails s)
it seems to refer to rvm and errors out
"/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)"

This specific project needs 2.6.3 ruby. I tried many options, searched across google and tried many but the issue remains. I was just trying to run a project i downloaded from GitHub (ror project with 2.6.3 ruby)

when i do rbenv list... i do see 2.6.3

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have completely [removed rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558763/13841038) from your system

Remove the `rvm/` directory and all the rubies built within it

```
$ rvm implode
```

Remove the final trace of `rvm`

```
$ gem uninstall rvm
```

Go to the home directory and list all hidden files:

```
$ ls -a
```

Check if there are any remaining RVM files in your home directory, if yes remove them:

```
$ rm  .rvm
$ rm  .rvmrc
```

Then [set rbenv](https://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally) to use 2.6.3 ruby-version:

```
$ rbenv local 2.6.3
```